# Question on application of a boolean when it is a variable? (word problem)

Tags: boolean, racket

I have a word problem-- It costs 20 cents (0.2 dollars) to print each page of a book. In addition to that, you have to purchase either a paperback cover ($ 1) or a hardback cover ($ 2.5). Write a function which produces the total cost (in dollars)?
This is my code so far (in the code, "n" is the number of pages and "cover?" is my boolean variable.

```
(define (total-cost n cover?)  
  (cond
   [(paperback-cover? true) (+ 1 (* 0.2 n))]
   [(hardback-cover? true) (+ 2.5 (* 0.2 n))]))
```

For some reason, my code isn't working. Can someone please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: @Diamoniner12345 you've asked 8 questions and gotten quite good answers, yet you haven't [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) a single one. This is not how this site works, you should show some appreciation for the people that take the time to help you, please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), it's so easy to just click the check mark right besides the best answers!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Sorry, I didn't know I had to do that. I'll keep it in mind for when I ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
#lang racket

(define (total-cost n cover)  
  (if (equal? cover "paperback") (+ 1 (* 0.2 n)) (+ 2.5 (* 0.2 n)))
)

(println (total-cost 100 "paperback"))

(println (total-cost 100 "hardcover"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#lang racket

; order-form : number symbol -> number
(define (order-form pages cover-type)
  (let* ([price-per-page 0.2]
         [page-cost (* pages price-per-page)]
         [cover-cost
          (cond
            [(equal? cover-type 'hardback) 2.5]
            [(equal? cover-type 'paperback) 1])]
         [total-cost (+ page-cost cover-cost)])
    total-cost))


;;; TEST
(order-form 10 'paperback)
(order-form 10 'hardback)
```